# Multiple DNS mappings for a host via DDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, bind, dhcp-server, ddns

I have a network in which DNS is automatically updated with a record for hosts when they get an address via DHCP (isc-dhcp-server & Bind configured with DDNS updates).  The DHCP server is configured so that a certain host with a complicated hostname gets a friendlier mapping [foo] on the DNS server via 'ddns-hostname' option in dhcpd.conf.  I also want this host to have a second record [bar] so it can be resolved via either name.  Since Dynamic DNS is in place, it is not possible to modify the zone file manually (normally I could just add multiple CNAME records).

How can I accomplish having multiple DNS records for a host via DDNS?  The 'ddns-hostname' option only allows one value, and having a second 'ddns-hostname' entry simply overwrites the first.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can modify the zone file manually, at least as far as I know.

What you need to be careful of is that you freeze the zone before modification or there is a possibility that you will create an out of sync condition for the zone file.

```
rndc freeze {zone}
```

After that, you can edit the zone file with your favorite editor.  After you finish

```
rndc thaw {zone}
```

I've been using this process for quite some time.

As for having ddns add multiple A records or CNAMES to the zone, I don't know that this is possible.  I've never found a solution to that issue and have gone the route of adding manual records for the few machines I need this capability for.